# Where is the correct place(s) in twentysixteen's header.php to add a Google webfont?

Tags: theme-development, templates, child-theme

I have a slightly tweaked child theme to twentysixteen (used solely on `https://CJSHayward.com` - feel free to view source!), and I would like to add a Google webfont. http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/how-add-google-web-fonts-wordpress-themes/ suggests (as one option) to put e.g. `<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Sigmar+One" rel="stylesheet">` before your theme imports its stylesheet. That sounds like sensible enough advice, but twentysixteen's `header.php` does not contain strings I could find like "css". As a result, I don't know where the last line is in `header.php` before the theme's stylesheet is loaded, or whether (in a child theme to twentysixteen) I should be editing some other file (and if so, which?).

I have provisionally placed `<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Sigmar+One" rel="stylesheet" />` in `header.php` just after the open HEAD tag, but I suspect there are better or more surgical placements.

Where, in a twentysixteen child, should I place an HTML tag to import a Google font or the like?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can place it in `header.php` between starting `<head>` and closing `</head>` tags and it should work properly.

Or perhaps a better solution would be to enqueue the style in functions.php

```
function google_fonts() {
$query_args = array(
    'family' => 'Sigmar+One'
);
wp_register_style( 'google_fonts', add_query_arg( $query_args, "//fonts.googleapis.com/css" ), array(), null );
        }

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'google_fonts');
```